# Replace value with associative array text keys

Tags: php

I am trying to replace the value of `$row['roles']` with an array:

```
$row['roles'] = array(
    "admin" => true,
    "user" => true
  );
```

Or

```
$row['roles'] = array("admin", "user"); // I think this is not posible, since php autogenerates the index keys.
```

This is the code I have that is not working for me:

```
$row['roles'] = '["admin","user"]';
$roles = json_decode($row['roles'], true);
foreach($roles as $role){
  $row['roles'][$role] = true; // Warning illegal string offset 'admin' 
}              
var_dump($row['roles']); // string '1"admin","user"]' (length=16)
```

Does anyone have any idea how to generate such array from the json string?
I have also tried generating the array with explode, but all I get is an indexed array `array(1=>admin,2=>user)`
I would like to do a `if(isset($row['admin'])` check.

Comment: Are you trying to construct a JSON string that represents your `$row['roles']` array?

Comment: `$row['roles'] = [];` before the `foreach`.

Comment: I am trying to build an array like this: `array('admin', 'user')` so I can check if the loged in user has admin or user access `if(isset($row['admin'])){ echo "admin Stuff" }`

Comment: You already have that array. An array cannot even not have indicies. Those are the values, not the indicies that you're currently using. `array('admin', 'user')` is identical to `array(0 => 'admin', 1 => 'user')`.

Comment: So I just had to empty the array before loading it again?

Comment: I mean, you're not emptying the array, you're replacing the string value in that top variable with an empty array. You could do the same just using a completely different variable or associative array key.

Comment: if(isset($row['roles']['admin'])){ echo "admin Stuff" } ?

Comment: $row is already array, just add admin too

Comment: @flakerimi But `$row['roles']` is a string. That's the issue.

Comment: Oh you mean this $row['roles'] = '["admin","user"]';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you have an error "Warning illegal string offset 'admin'" is that your array is not initialized as key => value array, so you can't use "admin" as a key.

Just reinitialize your array with this : $row['roles'] = [];
And your code will be working.

```
$row['roles'] = '["admin","user"]';
$roles = json_decode($row['roles'], true);

$row['roles'] = [];
foreach($roles as $role){
  $row['roles'][$role] = true;
}              
var_dump($row['roles']);
```

But depending on your real needs, I think that it should be really more simple.